# Handle Exception in ResponsesEntity java

Tags: java, http, response

I wonder how to handle exception in `ResponsesEntity`.
When it receive wrong url, it supposes to go to the `catch` block and display the `log`. But I keep getting error message in console. The `try-catch` not working as it not display log message.

```
@GetMapping("abc/{Id}")
    public ResponseEntity info(@PathVariable("Id") String id) {
        HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(buildHttpHeaders());
        String theUrl = url + "/xxx/transactions/" +id;
        ResponseEntity<TDto> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(theUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, TDto.class);
        TDto tdto = responseEntity.getBody();
        Tran tran = new Tran();
        try {
              tran.setDate(new Date());
              tran.saveAndFlush(tran); // save to database
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            log.info("Log: "+e);
        }
        return responseEntity;
    }
```

Error

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
    at com.rh.tranglo.controller.ApiController.retrieveTransactionInfo(ApiController.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
```

Is there a way to handle exception by displaying the `log` in `catch` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your catch block is not catching the exception then it means, you are wrapping the wrong code inside the try block. To know which code is actually throwing an exception I suggest you place break points in your code and run it through a debugger. I'm not familiar with what you want to achieve but looking at it I'm guessing the statement you are supposed to wrap inside the try block is this

```
ResponseEntity<TDto> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(theUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, TDto.class);
```

Also if you look at the log again more carefully you'll see something that will help you. The exception is originating from your code but the top exceptions are just spring exceptions. I think if you follow the log message and go down you'll see the line in your code that is throwing the exception.

**Update**

I think I understand your problem now. But your question is not properly asked. You have a controller that is mapped to a specific URL say /hello but when testing you pass /hi and you expected your controller method to catch the not found exception. Sorry spring does not work that way.

When a controller is mapped to a URL, the controller code will only be executed if the URL used in the call matches the URL the controller is mapped to. So in your case when you make a GET with another URL other than which your controller is mapped to, the code in the controller will never be executed. That's why you don't enter the catch block you put. Spring code is responsible for throwing the 404 exception not your code.

**Note** I'll be able to help you more when I properly understand your problem. It will do a lot of good if you could share the full stacktrace.

Comment: If I sent wrong url , I will get exception. The error pointed to this line.

Comment: which line? And the class Tran, where is it coming from. Can I take a look at it's documentation or source code?

Comment: Put a break point on that line then and run your code via a debugger. And see it'll fail on that line.

Comment: This `line ResponseEntity<TDto> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(theUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, TDto.class);`

Comment: if I need to insert `trans.setMessage("Error")` from catch block to database, is it possible?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Your problem seems to go way beyond this one question.

Comment: No, is same. I used log to test whether the catch block will get called or not.If yes I want it to insert error message in database.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the exact error you get from the console in the catch, aka-HttpClientErrorException

Comment: instead of log.info, try e.printStackTrace()

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually included responseEntity in your try-catch. try-catch will catch only exceptions that are within try { // all exceptions in between parenthesis will be caught }

```
@GetMapping("abc/{Id}")
public ResponseEntity info(@PathVariable("Id") String id) {
try {
    HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(buildHttpHeaders());

    String theUrl = url + "/xxx/transactions/" +id;
    ResponseEntity<TDto> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(theUrl, 
    HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, TDto.class);
    TDto tdto = responseEntity.getBody();
    Tran tran = new Tran();

          tran.setDate(new Date());
          tran.saveAndFlush(tran); // save to database
     }catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.info("Log: "+e);
    }
    return responseEntity;
}
```

It should look more like something like this if you want to catch throws from responseEntity , But in your case only exceptions thrown by this ones will be caught:

```
try {
          tran.setDate(new Date()); -> this will throw exceptions(very unlikely)
          tran.saveAndFlush(tran); -> or this will throw exceptions, 
    }
```

And any other exceptions won't be caught

Comment: if I need to insert `trans.setMessage("Error")` from catch block to database, is it possible?

Comment: If the exception is an error then it will break your program and you can't do anything, But most likely you get just some RuntimeException and you can do just about anything you want in catch block

Comment: do you know how to write this ? How to get Runtime Exception ?